# Can't figure out how inner product spaces work over $\mathbb {C} $

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products

I am working with complex numbers ($\mathbb {C} $).
I'm trying to figure this out:
$ \forall x,y\in V,\ \langle x,y\rangle =\overline {\langle y,x\rangle }$

When we talk about inner product space do I need to multiply between the vectors?
like normal multiplication between vectors? (only with complex numbers)
If anyone can give me an example for ($ \forall x,y\in V,\ \langle x,y\rangle =\overline {\langle y,x\rangle }$) (but with numbers to understand) it can greatly help.
Thank you.

Comment: In $\mathbb C^n$: $\langle(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\rangle=x_1\overline{y_1}+x_2\overline{y_2}+\ldots+x_n\overline{y_n}$ is one inner product (but there are many others!).

Comment: When you refer to multiplying between the vectors, do you mean taking the standard dot product (inner product) of two vectors with complex entries? As @StinkingBishop says, there are many inner products, so you need to specify which one.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with taking the complex conjugate of a complex number, as denoted by the overbar or sometimes by an asterisk (star)? That is, $\overline{a+bi} = a-bi$.

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers form a $1$-dimensional vector space over themselves with inner product $\langle x,\,y\rangle:=x\overline{y}$. We can also regard this as a $2$-dimensional space over the reals. Writing $x=a+bi, \,y=c+di$ gives $x\overline{y}=ac+bd+(bc-ad)i$. Either choice of scalars lets you verify $\langle x,\,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,\,x\rangle}$.

Comment: @NFLX If $y=c+di$, then $\overline{y}=c-di$ (complex conjugate), and so $x\overline{y}=(a+bi)(c-di)=ac+bd+(bc-ad)i$.